# How to create content controls in Microsoft Publisher 2010?

Tags: templates, microsoft-publisher

I know that content controls can be created in Microsoft Word 2010 by going to "Word Options" → "Customise the ribbon" and ticking the "developer" box.

But when I do this in Publisher, there is no option to create a content control.

I know that it can be done because there are textboxes in the default templates that act in the same way.

How can I create my own?